# Problema con un metodo

Tags: java, poo, arraylist, clase

Tengo un metodo que recibe un ArrayList de productos, cada producto tiene su codigo, importe, descripcion y stock.
Lo que deberia hacer el metodo es devolver el stock del producto si este esta en la lista (para eso se inserta el codigo de producto en los parametros), o devuelve 0 si el codigo de producto no esta en la lista.
El problema es que siempre devuelve 0 el metodo aunque SI EXISTA el producto con el codigo correspondiente.
aqui esta el metodo:

```
public static Integer devolverStock(ArrayList<Producto> e, Integer code) {
        for(Integer i=0;i<e.size();i++) {
            if(e.get(i).getCodigo()==code) {
                return e.get(i).getStock();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

esto es lo que hago en el metodo main:

```
System.out.println("Stock del producto 10234879: " + Producto.devolverStock(lista,10234879));
```

el problema es que SIEMPRE devuelve 0, da igual que el codigo exista en la lista, siempre me devuelve 0, y el producto existe porque lo comprobe yo mismo imprimiento la lista usando toString()

esta es la clase Producto:

```
package lista_productos;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Producto implements Comparable<Producto>{

    private Integer codigo;
    private String descripcion;
    private Double importe;
    private Integer stock;

    public Producto(Integer codigo, String descripcion, Double importe, Integer stock) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.importe = importe;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public String toString() {
            return "Codigo: " + this.getCodigo() + " | Descripcion: " + this.getDescripcion() + " | Importe: " + this.getImporte() + " | Stock: " + this.getStock() + "\n";
    }

    public int compareTo(Producto p) {
        if(this.getCodigo()>p.getCodigo()) return 1;
        if(this.getCodigo()<p.getCodigo()) return -1;
        return 0;
    }

    public void incrementar10() {
        setImporte(getImporte() + (getImporte()*10/100));
    }

    public static ArrayList<Producto> menos50Stock(ArrayList<Producto> e){
        ArrayList<Producto> menos50 = new ArrayList<Producto>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<e.size();i++) {
            if(e.get(i).getStock()<50) {
                menos50.add(e.get(i));
            }
        }
        return menos50;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Producto> mas50Stock(ArrayList<Producto> e){
        ArrayList<Producto> mas50 = new ArrayList<Producto>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<e.size();i++) {
            if(e.get(i).getStock()>=50) {
                mas50.add(e.get(i));
            }
        }
        return mas50;
    }

    public static Integer devolverStock(ArrayList<Producto> e, Integer code) {
        for(Integer i=0;i<e.size();i++) {
            if(e.get(i).getCodigo()==code) {
                return e.get(i).getStock();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public Double getImporte() {
        return importe;
    }

    public void setImporte(Double importe) {
        this.importe = importe;
    }

    public Integer getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Integer stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }






}

**el metodo main completo:**

package lista_productos;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Pruebas {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Producto> lista = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    ArrayList<Producto> menos50;
    ArrayList<Producto> mas50;

    Producto yerba = new Producto(12209999,"Yerba_Mate_Marolio_x1Kg",25.50,75);
    Producto vino = new Producto(00015470,"Vino_Balbo_x1Lt",60.00,100);
    Producto galletitas = new Producto(10002450,"Surtido_Bagley_x500g",40.00,100);
    Producto azucar = new Producto(10520123,"Azucar_Ledesma_x1Kg",50.00,25);
    Producto pan = new Producto(10234879,"Pan_xKg",35.50,12);

    lista.add(yerba);
    lista.add(vino);
    lista.add(galletitas);
    lista.add(azucar);
    lista.add(pan);

    Collections.sort(lista);

    lista.get(0).incrementar10();

    menos50 = Producto.menos50Stock(lista);

    mas50 = Producto.mas50Stock(lista);

    System.out.println(lista.toString());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(menos50.toString());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(mas50.toString());

    System.out.println("Stock del producto 10234879: " + Producto.devolverStock(lista,10234879));

}
```

}

Comment: ¿Qué hace el método `getCodigo()` y cómo está organizado tu ArrayList?

Comment: ahi lo edito y le agrego todo

Comment: Bien, ahora sí se ve el problema. Declaraste ese campo del tipo `Integer`, no `int`, lo cual quiere decir que `Integer` es una clase, no un primitivo, debes usar por eso `equals` en la comparación: `if(e.get(i).getCodigo().equals(code))` ... ¿Por qué? Porque cada código de producto es una *instancia*  de la clase `Integer` y debes comparar las instancias de los objetos, no los valores.

Comment: aaah, que boludo, y eso que sabia que no se pueden comparar objetos con los comparadores == , < , > etc. muchas gracias

Comment: ahi puse: if (e.get(i).getCodigo().equals(code)==true) y funciono

Comment: Poner `if ( valor.equals(otrovalor)==true ){`  es redundante, es como si pusieras `if(true==true)` o `if (true==false){ `, porque `equals` te devuelve ya un booleano. Con que pongas `if ( valor.equals(otrovalor) ){` es suficiente.

Comment: y si por ejemplo quisiera que entrara cuando la comparacion es falsa tampoco lo tengo que poner? o ahi si es necesario?

Comment: aaah, okey, muchas gracias genio

Comment: **P**: *«y si por ejemplo quisiera que entrara cuando la comparacion es falsa tampoco lo tengo que poner?»* **R**: No, tampoco, tan sólo tienes que negar la comparación con el símbolo `!`, por ejemplo: `if ( !valor.equals(otrovalor) ){` ... ahí estarías preguntando si es `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás comparando un **objeto del tipo `Integer`**, no un primitivo `int`, por tanto debes usar `equals` en al comparación:

```
public static Integer devolverStock(ArrayList<Producto> e, Integer code) {
        for(Integer i=0;i<e.size();i++) {
            if(e.get(i).getCodigo().equals(code)) {
                return e.get(i).getStock();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Puedes si quieres implementar un `for` un poco más agradable a la vista:

```
    public static Integer devolverStock(ArrayList<Producto> e, Integer code) {
        for(Producto p : e)
        {
            if (p.getCode().equals(code)) {
                return p.getStock();
            }
        }
            return 0;
    }
```